# drupal_goto overlay page

Tags: 7, users

I'm using drupal_goto to redirect users on login.
Administrators and 'other' are redirected to the dashboard. All works fine but I want to redirect to the dashboard in an administrative overlay.
(Path = #overlay=nl/admin/dashboard)
Chrome and Firefox alter the # to %23 so I get a page not found error.

Can this be done?

Here is the function:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_login().
 */
function myModule_user_login(&$edit, $account) {    
  $user_roles = array_intersect(array('other', 'administrator'), array_values($account->roles));
  if (!empty($user_roles)) {
    drupal_goto('admin/dashboard');
  } else {
    drupal_goto('');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a `fragment` to `drupal_goto()` as an option like so:

```
$options = array('fragment' => 'nl/admin/overlay');
drupal_goto('some-url', $options);
```

Reference for this can be found on the [`url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7) docs page (the docs page for `drupal_goto()` actually refers you to there as well).

Comment: With fragment $options = array('fragment' => overlay=admin/dashboard'); it's working properly, TY!